# WPF using static method to clear button's content

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a TicTacToe game and I am trying to reset a button's content using a static method in my code behind for a WPF. When the button is press it shows the content associated with the "Player" of who's turn it is. I have a `Player` class that stores information about the player, that is displayed in various locations. I have written a static method to reset the "game board", but when I run my method the button's content does not reset. Here is what my code looks like.

```
public class Player
    {
        public string plyName { get; set; }
        public int plyType { get; set; } // 0 = human player, 1 = basic AI, 2 = advanced AI
        public int plyScore { get; set; }
        public char plySymbol { get; set; }
        public int plyNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public static int round { get; set; }
    public static int numRounds { get; set; }
    public static int[,] gameBoard = new int[3, 3];

    public static Player Player1 = new Player();
    public static Player Player2 = new Player();
    public static Player currPlayer;
```

and here is my clearGameBoard Method:

```
public static void clearGameBoard ()
    {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.btnTL.Content = "";
        mw.btnTM.Content = "";
        mw.btnTR.Content = "";
        mw.btnML.Content = "";
        mw.btnMM.Content = "";
        mw.btnMR.Content = "";
        mw.btnBL.Content = "";
        mw.btnBM.Content = "";
        mw.btnBR.Content = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                App.gameBoard[i, j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnTL"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnTL_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnTM"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnTM_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnTR"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnTR_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnML"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnML_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnMM"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnMM_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnMR"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnMR_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnBL"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnBL_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnBM"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnBM_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnBR"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Click="btnBR_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Tic Tac Toe" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="199" FontSize="30"/>

</Grid>
```

I tried to just set the buttons content directly but got the error that "object reference required for non-static property". I'm sure it is an obvious mistake that I am making but I can't seem to find an answer on here that helps. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the mistake is that clearGameBoard method clears board in another window mw (`MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();`). as a quick hack you can get active window from `App.Current.MainWindow` and cast it to `MainWindow`. But things become really simpler if you read about and apply MVVM approach

Answer (score 0):

You create a new MainWindow without showing it instead of using the one displayed. Use [Application.Current.MainWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx).

This will solve your issue but you should probably learn about MVVM and binding, which are big features of WPF and provide a way more simple solution.